# eclipse egit working directory vs jenkins and git way

Tags: java, eclipse, git, jenkins, egit

i started to learn git, created a git repo in a svn way (many projects per repo) and started do develop the project

```
x/
+--.git/
      +--y/
         |--pom.xml
         +--rest of java files and folders
```

so actually root of my java project is `y` but root of git repo is `x`. eclipse handles it really nicely allowing you to specify 'working directory'/'path' inside the repo that becomes root of your project

but when i tried to integrate it with jenkins i realised that git way is 'one repo per project' and i can't provide such 'working directory' in jenkins.

my question is: what for eclipse introduced the concept of 'working directory'/'path' if it's incompatible with rest of the world? when should i use it?
i'm sure i'm missing something, but don't know what

Comment: Could you describe the problem with Jenkins in more detail? It's certainly possible to use that setup (we have it here). You probably just haven't found the right configuration option in Jenkins yet.

Comment: i mean that with above directory structure i can comfortably work with eclipse. eclipse will use `y` directory as a root of the project. however, jenkins require a path to git repo (which is `.../.git`) and cannot build maven project that is not in the root directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"many projects per repo" is called **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** in git world.
Limiting each repo to one project is better (and more compatible with other frameworks expectations, like Jenkins), but a git repo can reference many other repos through submodules.

The [working directory](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Working_Directory) is by default x, but could be any other path if you want to separate the actualt repo `x/.git` from the working directory (you could want to be elsewhere)